# Python progress bar GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I wonder if you can help me. I have seen code for creating a progress bar GUI and am trying to modify it slightly so that I can send the progress bar the value I want it to be. Below is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

class progress_bar(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
        self.progress.pack()
        self.val = 0
        self.maxval = 1
        self.progress["maximum"] = 1

    def updating(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.progress["value"] = self.val
        print(self.val)

        if self.val == self.maxval:
            self.destroy()

def test():
    for i in range(0, 101):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        app.updating(i/100)

app = progress_bar()
app.after(1, test)
app.mainloop()
```

When I run the code the print message progresively increases from 0 - 1 as expected, however while the GUI is created it remains empty until the program has finished and it closes as required. Can you tell me what I need to modify so the GUI updates please. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is that your `test` function blocks the `tkinter` event loop. That means that even though the progress bar's `value` gets updated, the progress never appears on the screen (since nothing gets redrawn until `test` ends).

To fix this, you need to get rid of the loop in `test` and instead use `tkinter` code to do the repeated updates.

Here's a modified version of `test` that should work:

```
def test(i=0):
    app.updating(i/100)
    if i < 100:
        app.after(100, test, i+1)
```

Rather than explicitly looping, it reschedules itself every 100 milliseconds. Rather than `i` being a loop variable, it is now an argument, and each scheduled call gets a larger `i` value than the one before it.